# HTML / JS - How to zoom in a table and drag it?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I have a table but it is and should be very small. Now I want the user to be able to zoom into the table with the mouse wheel, there I can write in or something similar. He should also be able to drag the table.

I have already researched a lot but found nothing in this direction, maybe you have found something or you can help me.

,

Something i found but that's not what i want:

```
object.style.width = "auto|length|%|initial|inherit"
```

Comment: Put every measurement to `rem`s. Now on scroll event change root element `font-size`. Or leave it for browser with `Ctrl + [scroll|+|-]`

Comment: To drag: look for jQueryUI draggable

Comment: How to drag i know but how to zoom in smoothly in the table without the browser-function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
let table = document.querySelector('table');
table.onwheel = function(e) {
  if (e.deltaY < 0) {
    table.style.fontSize = parseInt(getComputedStyle(table).fontSize) + 1 + 'px';
  } else if (e.deltaY > 0) {
    table.style.fontSize = parseInt(getComputedStyle(table).fontSize) - 1 + 'px';
  }
  e.preventDefault();
};
```

```html
<table border="1">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>foo</th>
      <th>bar</th>
      <th>baz</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>qux</td>
      <td>quxx</td>
      <td>quxxx</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```